# I need to cause a WordPress 503 (plugin related)

Tags: wordpress, 503-error

I currently work resolving things like this however I’m currently in a place where I need to cause a 503 error on WordPress because of a plugin in order to develop automation tools to quickly resolve this for end users.

Does anyone have a method of doing this easily?

I just really need a broken plugin to result in a 503 so I can write some script to find it reliably.

Comment: Just introduce a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you!!! wasn’t sure that would be enough to cause one but it’s worked! :)